# Upgrading from kernel 3.13 to 3.18 causes Unity not to load, wireless not to work (System specs included)

Tags: unity, wireless, upgrade, kernel

SYSTEM SPECS:

```
 Macbook Pro (64 bit), Ubuntu 14.04,

 kernel version: 3.13, 

 graphics drivers: nvidia-331
```

Recently I've been experiencing wi-fi problems on a regular basis in 14.04 with kernel version 3.13, and I was getting really annoyed. I did a bit of research and found a [bug report on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1297286)- the submitter reported that upgrading from the 3.13 kernel to 3.18 had solved his problem entirely, so I decided to try it out.

To upgrade my kernel I followed the instructions in the linked thread- I navigated to [the ubuntu kernel webpage (hopefully the right one)](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.18-vivid/) , dowloaded `linux-headers-3.18.0-031800-generic_3.18.0-031800.201412071935_amd64.deb`, opened the file with Software Center, and hit "install."

I didn't get any errors during the actual install process. However, when I rebooted my system I noticed that the errors/log output was different when the system was booting up (before it would always say "registered C22fgy.phy" or something similar- I dont remember). Now, however, the following errors show up.

```
[   0.026781] [Firmware Bug]: ioapic 2 has no mapping iommu, interrupt remapping will be disabled
[   1.219547] pci 0000:00:01.0: ASPM Could not configure common clock
[   2.629436] i8042: No controller found
```

The system booted to the login screen fine (Unity seemed to be working OK, with the widget bar functioning in the top of the screen). However as soon as I tried to login, I get a "system problem detected" window, and Unity doesnt load- my wallpaper shows up, but there's no desktop environment to accompany it (even the widgets in the top corner disappeared). On top of that, wifi doesnt seem to be working at all under 3.18 (havent tried wired yet). I can still get into the shell via cntrl+alt+f1+fn (I'm on a laptop), but I'm not really sure what I'd use it for. Running `uname -r` verifies that the 3.18 kernel has actually been installed.

I can, using grub, still boot normally using the 3.13 kernel (that's actually what I'm typing this from).

I was hoping you guys could help me out with (correctly) installing the 3.18 kernel, as well as with resolving the problems that are popping up for me. If you guys need any more information, I'd be happy to provide it.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me you have an xyz problem, mention x problem, try y solution and now trying to solve unrelated z problem. Also I personally wouldn't recommend installing unsigned kernel packages, leave you without security updates , without ubuntu patches.

Answer (score 0):

I read the "advice" given on that bugreport but I think it was wrong. You're not supposed to download one .deb package but 3, depending on the architecture.

See more details here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds#Installing_upstream_kernels

It is a good idea to revert to using nouveau (the open source nvidia driver) if you're going to test a mainline kernel as various modules like the ones for nvidia, virtualbox won't get built when installing this kernel.

A bit more info about this, here:
[dkms: rebuild kernel module for manually installed upstrem kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115188/dkms-rebuild-kernel-module-for-manually-installed-upstrem-kernel)

When messing with the kernel it's a good idea to do a bit more research before committing to making changes to your system.