# USB keyboard does not work after each time kernel gets updated

Tags: drivers, kernel, keyboard, dkms, usbhid

I've had an old issue with my USB connected keyboard specially after kernel updates. The problem in the first place is the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Windows</kbd>/<kbd>Super</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> buttons are all mapped to <kbd>Shift</kbd> button that was getting solved by the [aziokbd driver](https://bitbucket.org/Swoogan/aziokbd). But every time after kernel updates and reboot, the whole keyboard stops working and I can't even login to my Ubuntu account without OnScreen keyboard. (The back-light of the keyboard is working though; so the power of USB port is connected).

I'm now booted with the older kernel version (4.4.0-21) from Grub menu to post this question.

Until now I have followed the quirks method [described here](https://askubuntu.com/q/605251/25831), [this method](https://askubuntu.com/a/115200/25831) (with the latest kernel (4.4.0-24) replaced at the end of the command), and also [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/53562/25831) but had no success.

what's the workaround about this issue which repeats with every kernel update and the reboot after it? Could I somehow switch to the latest kernel while am booted with older version which works with the keyboard and install the [aziokbd driver](https://bitbucket.org/Swoogan/aziokbd) on that problematic kernel? Or manipulate the latest kernel while am on the older one?

Maybe even there would be a way to prevent this problem after each kernel update? Currently it's possible to login and install *aziokbd driver* all with On-Screen keyboard but it's still annoying to do that after each time kernel gets updated.

**Edit:**
I'm now on Ubuntu `16.04`, the shipped kernel which I installed *aziokbd driver* on, is `4.4.0-21` and the updated version is `4.4.0-24`. However I had this problem on Ubuntu `14.04` (which has been upgraded directly to `16.04`) and several kernel updates from its release date.

Thanks

Comment: What are "this" and "that" kernel? What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: @Pilot6 The question has been edited.

Comment: @DummyBeginner, basic function of DKMS is to build the driver for each new installed kernel automatically.  Could you get the output of these commands `dkms status`,  `uname -a`  & `more /proc/cmdline` when this happens (running new kernel and keyboard is not working). Does `sudo dkms autoinstall -k 4.4.0-24-generic` build the driver for the new kernel, run `dkms status` to check? As I know you have to use the full version `4.4.0-24-generic` not just ver sion number `4.4.0-24`.