# upgraded to kernel 5.4.0-49

Tags: networking, server, kernel, updates, ssh

I remotely update ubuntu server. When I rebooted and tried to ssh back into server, the network was not found.

Went down last night and the server was up and running, but when I ran `ifconfig` it was only showing
`inet 127.0.0.1` network.

I have lost both my internal ethernet cards. I have been reading about it and going back down to reboot back into older `kernel 5.4.0-48` and hopefully get the server back up and running.

I rebooted into old kernel and everything works fine, and at the moment I am using the old kernel and all seems fine.

I got the same `lspci` output on both kernels:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family ME Interface #1
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller #2
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev d0)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev d0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev d0)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller #1
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z97 Chipset LPC Controller
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

I get the following messages in the sys log

Jan  5 09:04:00 server-one ifup[836]: Cannot find device "p4p1"
Jan  5 09:04:00 server-one ifup[733]: ifup: failed to bring up p4p1
Jan  5 09:04:00 server-one ifup[853]: Cannot find device "p2p1"
Jan  5 09:04:00 server-one ifup[733]: ifup: failed to bring up p2p1
Jan  5 09:04:00 server-one systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan  5 09:04:00 server-one systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan  5 09:04:00 server-one systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.

I have ran dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc' and the list is empty. does that mean no broken packages.
The network interfaces are failing to load in new kernel but they load fine in older kernal.

I upgraded server 16.04 to 18.04 then upgraded to 20.04 could there be older packages still installed that needs to be looked at. I have been reading about it for a couple of days and would be grateful for any help

Their has been a kernel update to 5.4.0-60. Updated and now when it boots into new kernal the network interfaces are still not found. When I run ip a it is saying
eth0 and eth1 are both down. These cards were previously known as p4p1 and p2p1.
What is the work round to get network interfaces working.
Another thing now is when I boot into previous 5.4.0-48 it does not work anymore.

Are there any hints on what I need to do to find out what's broken. thanks for any help

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages in `/var/log/syslog` that might point to a problem? Could you share the output of `lspci`? This should show which specific network hardware you're using. From this it will be easier to see what might have happened.

Answer (score 1):

basically I had to rename p4p1 to eth1 p2p1 to eth0 in /ect/network/interfaces.

then I had to rewrite my iptables changing too above. I have a working server identical at home and I did not have to change anything. eth0 and eth1 is not used. Very strange as I check my home server before I do anything with the working one.

Comment: I ran into the same issue (with a single network card renamed from `p2p1`->`eth0`)! I installed a lot of updates so I'm not sure what exactly triggered the change. I also learned about `ifconfig -a` that listed `eth0` even when it was not up.

Answer (score 0):

when a older kernel is running well.

1. check if update was without error, meaning packages are in good status; and package linux-generic is on your system.

   `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'`

If not check with

```
df -h;df -i
```

free place and inodes are there (especially you have an own /boot filesystem)
[Free place in /boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)
and how to proceed

[fixing unterupted apt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425502/how-do-i-continue-configuration-if-apt-get-was-interrupted)

2. Looking for closed source modules

   `dkms status`

is every module  successfully build and installed in the new kernel.

If not boot the concerned kernel

[dkms autoinstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115188/dkms-rebuild-kernel-module-for-manually-installed-)

Comment: @Bill Inglis `dkms status` please.